# What's the difference between gevent.wait and gevent.joinall?

Tags: python, gevent

Let's say `tasks` is a list of `Greenlet` objects. Now what's the difference between

```
gevent.wait(tasks)
```

and

```
gevent.joinall(tasks)
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not much! `joinall` actually calls `wait` internally, and is a pretty short function ([source code](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/c6a8b9ac952b8dead0018f5e2ef027f1b271d788/gevent/greenlet.py#L610-L630)):

```
def joinall(greenlets, timeout=None, raise_error=False, count=None):
    if not raise_error:
        return wait(greenlets, timeout=timeout, count=count)

    done = []
    for obj in iwait(greenlets, timeout=timeout, count=count):
        if getattr(obj, 'exception', None) is not None:
            if hasattr(obj, '_raise_exception'):
                obj._raise_exception()
            else:
                raise obj.exception
        done.append(obj)
    return done
```

As you can see, unless you pass `raise_error=True`, `joinall` is essentially a passthrough to `wait`.

If you do pass `raise_error=True`, then `joinall` goes through your greenlets, and raises an exception if one of your them raises one (note that it uses `iwait` instead of `wait`, so the exception will be raised as soon as one greenlet raises).